# Seamlessly adding 1 to the previous row value?

Tags: php, mysql

I want to add 1 to the value of the previous row for `hit_count`, but I'm afraid doing it may not be safe if multiple queries are being run quickly (i.e. the page is being loaded several times a second - this is for a web-app I'm making, and so I want to make sure any amount of page loads is supported well).

**Here's what I had in mind:**

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM rotation");
$fetch = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);

$update_hit = $fetch['hit_counter']+1;

$query = "INSERT INTO rotation (hit_counter, rotation_name) VALUES ('$update_hit', '$rotation_name')";
$result = mysql_query($query);
```

I thought about setting the `hit_counter` column to a `UNIQUE KEY`, but I don't know what else I'd do after that.

I would use `AUTO_INCREMENT` but the problem is, I need the actual `hit_counter` value within the rest of the script.

Any ideas, comments, advice would be greatly appreciated!

**Edit:** I used `hit_count` and `hit_counter`, was a typo. Updated to avoid any confusion.

Comment: do you want to UPDATE a value into an sql row or create a new row? How about $rotation_name it is another record column or an user input?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [DUPLICATE KEY functionality](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html) when you make name + counter a unique value:

```
INSERT INTO rotation SET hit_counter = 1, rotation_name= 'name' 
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE hit_counter = hit_counter + 1
```

Performance wise (and if your requirements allow it) I advice pushing updates in bulk (per 100 hits) using a caching mechanism like f.e. memcached.

Comment: I thought `SET` only worked with `UPDATE`? I would use something like a caching mechanism, but the variance in the amount of hits is too great (i.e. some users may receive 10 hits in a single day which means stats would not update until after 10 days, while some may receive 1,000+ an hour).

Comment: `SET` works with `INSERT` too. And you could of course go for a period-update. Once an hour if it suits you. This all depends on the requirements.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `AUTO_INCREMENT`, if you need the inserted id within the rest script, you can use [mysql_insert_id](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-insert-id.php) to get it.

Comment: So, I could literally just do something like `$id = mysql_insert_id()` and it'll assign the value? What if there's two `AUTO_INCREMENT` columns? (Is it even possible to have two)?

Comment: No, it is not possible to have two AUTO_INCREMENT columns.