# Generating a random file name using while()?

Tags: php, mysql, while-loop

I'm using a `while()` loop to create a random file name, check it against a database, then if it already exists, loop. I'm just a little worried my syntax/usage is off, as I've only done this once before ages ago, and haven't used a `while()` loop in this way since then.

**Here's my code:**

```
$i = 0;
while(++$i) {
    $file_name = md5(mt_rand(0,9999999)) . ".php";
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM x WHERE file_name = '{$file_name}'");

    if(mysql_num_rows($result) == 0) { break; } else { continue;}
}
```

Would this work, and if not, what's wrong with it?

I know it's a petty question, but testing out whether or not this would work seems a lot more "tasky" (need to create a new table, alter the file name to choose from 1 - 3 things, display a message instead of continue etc.

Any help, as always, would be appreciated!

Comment: Just so you know, there is a built in php function that creates a file with a unique name in it's folder: `tempnam()` http://php.net/manual/en/function.tempnam.php

Comment: This code **doesn't protect** from having 2 same filenames in a table. Just because it the same random filename can be generated twice in simultaneously running scripts.

Comment: Oh cool. Will the default file extension for `tempnam()` be .php, or would I need to append .php to it somehow?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need `$i`, since you're not using it, and you don't need to `continue` in a loop - the loop will automatically loop, that's what it does. You only need to `break` when you reach the condition under which you want to end the loop:

```
while(true) {
    $file_name = md5(mt_rand(0,9999999)) . ".php";
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM x WHERE file_name = '{$file_name}'");

    if (mysql_num_rows($result) == 0) break;
}
```

You're using hashes in a slightly broken way though. You should be generating a random string *longer* than an MD5 hash, not shorter. Right now you only have 10,000,000 possible filenames (0..99999999) instead of the full 2^128 that a MD5 can produce. Instead of worrying about hash collisions in a space as large a 2^128, you have a much higher chance of simply generating the same numbers twice, causing multiple trips to the database.

Comment: Brilliant! I'll accept your answer when the timer drops. Also as in your example, I often see people running `if()` statements without encasing the outcome in parentheses, any chance you could explain the rule that permits the two/the difference?

Comment: `if`/`else`/`while` all accept "blocks". A block is any single statement, like `break;`, or group of statements, wrapped by braces. You only *have* to wrap the body of your `if`/`while`/control flow structures in braces if you have multiple statements.

Comment: Cool thanks! Do you know any additions I can make to quickly extend the the MD5 hash? I'm just trying to make random file names (regardless of format), but it's always good to know how to use something correctly.

Comment: This problem has been [solved many times](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bphp%5D+generate+random+string&submit=search) in the past.

Answer (score 2):

> I know it's a petty question, but testing out whether or not this would work seems a lot more "tasky" (need to create a new table, alter the file name to choose from 1 - 3 things, display a message instead of continue etc.

Taking the approach that the code does is also more "tasky" than necessary. It's workable, but why not let the database do the "create a unique file ID" work for you?

Define the file_name column in x to instead be a file_id column which is `bigint(20) auto_increment` or something like that. Then in the PHP code, issue a query to create a new row, grab the guaranteed-unique numeric ID, and transform it into a file name.

Comment: Thanks for the idea but according to  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7398152/seamlessly-adding-1-to-the-previous-row-value, it's impossible to have a table where two columns are `AUTO_INCREMENT`, and I require the `AUTO_INCREMENT` feature for another column :(.

Comment: So use the value from the existing `AUTO_INCREMENT` column? Does it not suit your purposes, even if that's not what it was originally intended for?

Answer (score 1):

This will work but you can change the line: while(++$i) into while(true)